Are there any advocates of "King James Bible Only" today who use the original 1611 version?
Are there any advocates of "King James Bible Only" today who insist using only the original 1611 version?  What reasons do they give?  For example, do they reject the Young Literal Translation that is also faithful to Textus Receptus?
The real old English is extremely hard to understand.

I've used the KJV myself since I was a child (I am now in my mid seventies) and I have never yet found anyone who uses the 1611. Everyone that I have known of has used the 1769. The NKJV was supposed to be an improvement. Sadly, in my own judgment, it has not been, as it leans towards the Critical Text rather than being truly faithful to the Textus Receptus.

A better question than simply asking the existence of such Bible readers is this: "what reasons would a KJV-only believer give for rejecting a faithful rendering of Textus Receptus into modern English such as the Young Literal Translation?"  Another worthy question: "Do KJV only believers reject a faithful translation of Textus Receptus into a language other than English, and if that is so, how would they evangelize to the ends of the world without first enrolling them in ESL courses?".

@MikeMcCain I decided to edit your question so it brings out the latent issues more, but if that is not your intention. please roll it back.

@NigelJ That second question has not been asked, so I will ask it.  Can I confirm it with you (for my initial research for that question, per SE practice) that you are fine with the common use of Masoretic Hebrew text for the textual basis of the OT?  What issues would you have with the OT portion of ESV, for instance?

@GratefulDisciple I am not a 'KJV only' person. I commonly refer to YLT and the EGNT interlinear (Englishman's Greek New Testament) both of which translate the Textus Receptus.

@NigelJ I gather as much.  "KJV-only" is just a label, but wouldn't you fit the profile for the "Textus Receptus Only" group described by James White in this Wikipedia section?  IMPORTANT Note: I'm not in the business of labeling a person but understanding them.  So my question remains as to your opinion whether the use of Masoretic text by non-Textus-Receptus bible translations is okay, or whether there is a particular textual variation AND/OR translation method that SHOULD be used?  I invite you to answer my recent Q.

@GratefulDisciple Which question is that ?

@NigelJ https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/103446/10672.  My inquiry to you above (about proper use of Masoretic text for modern OT translations) is pursuant to the research for that question.

@GratefulDisciple I am fine with the TR being translated into other languages. I am also fine with the KJV being improved as it is not perfect by any means. But the Revision of 1881 subsituted another Greek Text and did not actually do as was intended - improve the KJV. The NKJV is not an improvement as it, also, leans to the Critical Text. I am also fine with the Masoretic and for the Masoretic to be translated into other languages. I do not think the KJV to be 'inspired'. It is scripture that is 'God-breathed'. I looked at your question and felt no urge to answer it. I may do so later.

@NigelJ I understand your point about NKJV.  By "scripture" that is 'God-breathed' where do you locate it?  Is it the lost original Hebrew and Greek manuscript?  Is it the available edition we have now, such as Masoretic text & Textus Receptus?  Or some other thing that may not be physical but yields a physical manifestation, like the words in the author's mind to be committed to manuscript?  Or is it the effect of reading any proper Bible, which by that reading presents scripture as "word of God" to the Bible reader today?

Please, anyone, edit my question in any way that gives a more complete answer.

@MikeMcCain In SE sites, the OP (you) has the privilege and responsibility to frame your intention as clearly as possible.  If there are issues you want to include in your question, please edit the Q yourself, and we (the community) can help make the question clearer, focused, and objective.  But we cannot read your mind.  Welcome to C.SE; its good for you to be here.

@NigelJ My latest question is "gift" for you, a Q that hopefully be useful for you, as I sympathize with your wanting to read God's word as faithful as possible.  Feel free to suggest how I can improve the Q to aide proponents of Textus Receptus to have the 21st century tools to read the Bible better.

I have talked to several "King James Bible Only" believers. We did not discuss the pros or cons of Young, s translation. I do get the feeling from what we discussed and from what I have read, that they hold the KJV as superior to any other Bible translation, because the translators were "inspired." That word may not be directly mentioned but it is implied.

@NigelJ I found EGNT 3rd Edition (1896) scanned in archive.org.  Is there a later edition?

@GratefulDisciple EGNT (1896) Third Edition is what I use at home and online. I don't know of any later edition. I would doubt there is.

@GratefulDisciple       Neither can my wife.

I am a King James Only (as is my church) and I use the Original 1611 along with the 1769.
The spelling is different, but the words are the same. The original 1611 is not that difficult to read. Just because the spelling is off, that does not mean that you cannot understand it.

It would be great if you could give the reasons, and also on whether you approve of using YLT.

May I ask who you are with ? It is  very unusual to use the 1611. I am most interested.
