How do "KJV-only" believers deal with Bible translations into other languages for evangelism and for Bible study by non-English speakers?
One core reason of the "KJV-only" tenet that I often encounter when speaking to its proponents is their insistence that the original-language textual basis for the NT MUST BE the Textus Receptus as opposed to the Nestle-Aland.  An example they often give is that the latter text is more susceptible to Trinitarian and Christological heresies because the textual basis for both doctrines is "weaker".  There are also other doctrines that could be affected, not relevant to the question here.
As far as I know, they are fine with the common use of Masoretic Hebrew text for the OT translation.
The obvious question is what to do with evangelism.  Is it okay to do Bible translations to Chinese Mandarin (to use an example) when using Textus Receptus as the basis for NT while using KJV 1611/1769 for translation guidance?  Otherwise, evangelism would necessarily involve teaching them English first, although I can foresee how they would spread the gospel in Mandarin first.  But would they insist that proper Bible study can only be done in English using KJV 1769?  Can Bible Study by people who have low proficiency in English be done, in principle, with non-English translations that has been "certified" as faithful to Textus Receptus?  Or Bible studies using those Bible translations will forever be deemed as having a "second class citizen" status?  Or do they adopt the position of most evangelicals today, that proper Bible study should be done by consulting the original texts (thus studying Greek & Hebrew in seminary) although lay Bible readers can profit from reading a translation?
P.S. From reading Wikipedia it turns out there are 5 variations of this movement (by apologist James White).  It would be helpful for the one answering this question to identify which group's perspective they are answering from.  This question is primarily interested in the answers coming from either the "Textus Receptus Only" group or "The Inspired KJV Group".

I think this has largely been addressed in the linked question.

I have talked to King James Bible advocates, that hold the King James Bible as being a higher authority and more accurate than even the various Textus Receptus texts.

@curiousdannii OK.  I should have searched the site first.
